# Android default style notification with custom content

Tags: android, notifications, user-experience, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I've been looking allover the place for the styles that the default android notification view uses but I can't find it. I essentially want to make my notification look just like the standard notifications for each api, but with a custom layout(music controls). I can do that with setContent() on the notification but then I lose the left large icon that every other notification has and it looks out of place. I'd just like to have the customisation of setContent() with the style of a normal notification.

Answer (score 1):

You should only use a RemoteView if none of the other notification styles work for you. I think you should be able to use one of the big view styles. These style are documented in the training guide for notifications, under Using [Big View Styles](http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/expanded.html)

Is this not what you're looking for?